# Крашится игра на Android

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, admob

Импортировал плагин AdMob. На этапе Unity всё нормально работало. Сбилдил проект, установил на телефон. При запуске приложение крашится, в логах нашёл это:

09-05 23:58:06.250 20202 20202 E AndroidRuntime:
09-05 23:58:06.250 20202 20202 E AndroidRuntime: * Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here: *
09-05 23:58:06.250 20202 20202 E AndroidRuntime: * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad ... e-manifest *
09-05 23:58:06.250 20202 20202 E AndroidRuntime: * to find your app ID. *
09-05 23:58:06.250 20202 20202 E AndroidRuntime:

---

Comment: Это не обязательно причина креша. Запустите на эмуляторе и смотрите в LogCat, там будет что-то получше в момент падения.

Comment: Не знаю, как на `android`, но на `ios` из-за не прописанного `id AdMob` приложение крешится.